# Putting headers back when Apache strips them out

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, etag

I'm trying to implement ETags in my PHP script. `$hash` is a 40 character hex string, and the RFC for ETags says there's no maximum length.

```
header("X-ETag: $hash");    
header("ETag: $hash");
```

The first header, which is just a test, comes through properly; when I inspect the request in Chrome, I see the header. But, the second (actual) `ETag` header doesn't show up. I suspect my server administrator is stripping certain headers in the Apache configuration, and `ETag` is one of them.

I tried wrapping `$hash` with double quotes but it made no difference.

Can I override this behavior at the `.htaccess` level so my `ETag` header sent from PHP goes through?

Answer (score 0):

It was an evil `Header unset ETag` directive in a `.htaccess` file. Removing that made the ETag show up.